# how to show the field data of one app model on the other app template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Well, I am creating a user profile where the user can see his all posts which he has been uploaded. But I don't understand one thing that how could I possibly grab the fields of Post model from Posts/models.py and show them on the template which I have created in another app (Profiles) templates.
The reason I am trying to access them on other app is that I want to show them in the userprofile.html template. Just like Facebook posts. And please tell me if you know that it is not possible with django?

posts/models.py :

```
class Post(models.Model):


    username = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=("user name"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(('Description'),max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(('Content Title'), max_length=250)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    image_data = models.ImageField(upload_to='User_Posts', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

profiles/views.py

```
from posts.model import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'userpost_list' 
    template_name = 'profiles/userprofile.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username = self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.object.filter(username = user).order_by('-create_date')
```

profiles/templates/profiles/userprofile.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    {% for post in userpost_list %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><a  href="">{{ posts.post.title }}</a> <img src="" alt="not found" height="60" width="60" style="float:right ;border-radius: 20px;" ></h1>

        <div class="date">
            <p>
                <!-- Published on: {{ object.author.post.create_date|date:"D M Y" }} -->
            </p>
         </div> 
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access any app from any other app.  You just need to do the necessary model imports which you are doing.  Looks like you just need to tweak your line of code in the template from:

```
<h1><a  href="">{{ posts.post.title }}...
```

to:

```
<h1><a  href="">{{ post.title }}...
```

and when you decide to use it.

```
<!-- Published on: {{ object.author.post.create_date|date:"D M Y" }} -->
```

to:

```
<!-- Published on: {{ post.create_date|date:"D M Y" }} -->
```

The reason is that your queryset is returning a dataset of the Post model.  So you are already in it.

Comment: Okay Thank You you answered. by the way never mind but I applied those changes which you said but still nothing is printing.

Answer (score 0):

It just done by importing model from the app you want to use model to other app. And that it. This is python OOP(object oriented programming) concept.